# How to convert a char array that contains 0 or 1's into a decimal in C?

Tags: c

I have a string x that I need to convert into a hex format:

```
char x[5];
x[0]='0';
x[1]='1';
x[2]='0';
x[3]='1';  //x contains value of 0xA or decimal 10;
x[4]='\0';
```

Now how can I convert this and store it into an unsigned integer variable so the variable would be of value 0xA;

Thanks.

Comment: That number is 101 which is actually 0x5.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: Depends on which direction you read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the number is stored in reversed direction, which is not natural for human to read, but quite a natural way to represent number as the index refers to the power of 2 that should be applied.

There is no existing library to do the conversion for you, you need to write code to parse it yourself:

```
int i = 0;
unsigned int result = 0;

while (x[i]) {
    result |= (x[i] == '1') << i;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for a library but this does the trick.

Comment: @SS.: I don't think there are any though, at least among the standard ones. External library probably has.

Comment: This has my bits reversed so a character array of 0001 actually returns 8 instead of 1.  What is this due to? Endianness?

Comment: @ddelnano: Read the question. This solution doesn't apply to your use case. For your case, `result = (result << 1) | (x[i] == '1')`

Answer (score 2):

Why is the string in x in reversed order?

```
char x[5] = {'1', '0', '1', '0' };
unsigned int result = 0;
int i = 0;
while(x[i] != 0)
{
    result = result * 2 + x[i]-'0';
}
```

Comment: I assumed that this didn't work for me because I have it in reverse order.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *x = "0101";
```

Does not equal 0xA or decimal 10.  Binary '1010' would, maybe that's what you meant?

Simple way to convert string-represented numbers is strtol, among many other functions like atoi.  strtol at least allows a radix to be supplied.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol

Something like:

```
unsigned long val = strtol(x, NULL, 2);
```

Comment: I should have clarified that element 0 of the array was to be considered the least significant.  therefore char *x="1010".

Comment: Ok, well if the string is stored properly like that, then strtol should work fine.  Otherwise you might have to flip the string or parse it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I guess this wasn't working because I have it stored in reverse order.